# ～のも当然だ , use of も to soften

Tags: particle-も

> 彼女｛かのじょ｝が怒る｛おこる｝のも当然｛とうぜん｝だ。
> "It's natural that she should be angry." (sentence:248283, Core2000)

I asked a question about the preceding sentence's usage of も, and naruto explained the も serves to soften the sentence. I found the grammar explanation [here](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%82%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86%E3%81%9C%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0-no-mo-touzen-da/), but still didn't quite understand も in this context.

I'm wondering, does も replace another particle here? How the sentence could make sense without も, if 怒るの stood alone without a particle. Would 彼女が怒るのに当然だ or 彼女が怒るのは当然だ make sense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [も in 「Vのもアレなんだけど」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/%e3%82%82-in-v%e3%81%ae%e3%82%82%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ac%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e3%81%a9). This も makes the sentence milder and more reserved. It doesn't mean "also". I don't understand what you mean by "flipped word order", but the sentence is roughly the same as 彼女が怒るのは当然だ. Nothing is flipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

彼女が怒るのに当然だ doesn't make sense. 彼女が怒るのは当然だ is valid, and has almost the same meaning as 彼女が怒るのも当然だ.

The slight difference I can think of is that 彼女が怒るのは当然だ is more natural when it's paired with a reason why she's angry e.g. 彼女が怒るのは当然だよ、だって約束の時間に3時間も遅れてきたんだから.

On the other hand, 彼女が怒るのも当然だ sounds like both the speaker and listener know the reason already, or the speaker doesn't really want to focus on the reason.