# Trouble understanding のも in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-も, nominalization

I am having trouble understanding the significance of のも in this sentence:

そう考えるのも当然だ。

Comment: Can you explain in what way you are having trouble?  What is your understanding?  Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58433/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55970/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55266/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そう考えるのも当然だ means “It’s natural for you/him/her/them to think so.”

の makes a verb a noun. In this sentence, そう考えるの is the noun.

そう考えるのは当然だ almost has the same meaning, but there’s little difference. そう考えるのは当然だ sounds like the listener doesn’t know or think that it’s natural for you/him/her/them to think so.

Comment: I made a fatal mistake. そう考えるのは当然だ sounds like the listener doesn’t know or think that it’s natural for you/him/her/them to think so. This is right. I had written the contrary.