# What nuance does も add instead of が?

Tags: particle-が, particle-も

1. 最新技術をもってすればその開発**も**難しくないだろう。
2. 最新技術をもってすればその開発**が**難しくないだろう。

Since 2) is a complete sentence and doesn't need any more context to perfectly/accurately understand it(i think).
Can 1) also be considered a complete sentence which doesn't need any more context to perfectly/precisely/accurately understand it?

If **YES**, What nuance does も add instead of が?

Comment: Related, perhaps: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58433/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55266/9831

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if my format for an answer is incorrect.

Both can be considered a complete sentence.

(1) implies that development is already in progress, and having the new tech will probably make the originally difficult development no longer difficult. (2) only says that development will probably not be difficult with the new tech, with no indication that the development has started yet.

Comment: So you think 2) is a natural sentence?

Comment: But I thought what decides that the developement 'has already started' is the 'その' no? And since 'the developement' has already been considered in the 'speech', I think it has really already 'started' regardless of whether it started in reality or not.
And finally, why would a Japanese care about this detail of 'having started' while an English would just say [that development will probably not be difficult with the new tech] and won't even bothers his head with this 'maybe unuseful' detail.?????

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I did not explain correctly. A development has multiple stages, mainly planning, executing, and debugging/troubleshooting. (2) could be used at any of these stages, simply stating that development will be not as difficult with the new tech. However, you will not use (1) at the planning stage (unless you are stuck at brainstorming).

My point is that (1) will give the impression that the speaker have found a solution to a problem, whereas in (2) the speaker simply stated a suggestion. This is very important in Japanese society when they are trying to climb the ladder.

Comment: ^Continuing my previous comment, as a first-time stack exchange user, I realized it will probably be better by posting a comment instead of making an answer. Sorry for my inexperience and the inconvenience. (>.<)

Comment: @RikKa What i learned about も here is that one its functions is expressing [exclamation] or [admiration].
I think both of them fit in my example sentence.

Comment: "も” expresses its exclamation through its meaning of "also", "too", emphasizing the subject's meaning. This usage does not quite make sense in this sentence.

On the contrary, "も” also expresses "again", "already", as an abbreviation of "もう”. So it just comes down to how does one interpret the sentence. I believe this interpretation will make more sense than the above.

Comment: @RikKa You justified your point of view brilliantly!
This made me come back to my confusion about も usage.
If you check this https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32886/odd-use-of-%e3%82%82-has-me-stumped
you'll find in the answer:
Amateur translators will often force an "also" into their translation when faced with this unfamiliar usage because they feel uncomfortable interpreting noun + も as meaning anything other than "also".

ODD USE OF も HAS ME STUMPED! :(

Comment: @RikKa If i go and accept your answer though, this will make every sentence i encounter including も an ambiguous sentence that needs the interpretation of a culturalist Japanese rather than a grammarian.  Wouldn't it?