# How does 何だけど fit in here?

Tags: meaning

In steins;gate there is this conversation:

- 自分で言いだしておいて **何だけど**―
  全部のＤメールを取り消すなんて
- ああ結構 重労働だな

The translation says the following:

- " I realize that I was the one who suggested it, but cancelling all those D-mails.. "
- "Yeah, it will be pretty tough"
  What is the function of 何だけど here? How does it mean "I realize that I was the one who suggested it..." ?

I've also seen 何だけど similarly used in death note "立ち話も何ですから... ここへどうぞ"
where it means "Talking while standing is all fine, but come and take a seat", here I can somewhat make sense of it, the 何 implying that 立ち話 is questionable. But I don't understand what's going on in the steins gate conversation...

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55361/45489

Comment: Related: [Need help with translating 今更聞くのもアレなんだけど](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26127/43676)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This usage of 何だけど should be considered as a set phrase meaning *it is awkward/weird/strange*, indicating some inconsistencies between what was said before and what the speaker is going to say.

Here, a literal translation would be

- 自分で言いだしておいて This is what I proposed myself
- 何だけど― so it is awkward (to add/say this)
- 全部のＤメールを取り消すなんて (are we really going to do such a thing as) cancelling all those d-mails..

---

立ち話もなんですから is *It is awkward to keep standing while we talk*.